# Not sure what the Python documentation says about user-defined method objects here

Tags: python, class, methods

From the Python Language Reference [*Data Models* section](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), under the *User-defined methods* heading:

> When the attribute is a user-defined method object, a new method object is only created if the class from which it is being retrieved is the same as, or a derived class of, the class stored in the original method object; otherwise, the original method object is used as it is.

What does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2 *binds* functios when you look up a name on a class or an instance, see the [*descriptor protocol*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). When doing this on a class, the result is an *unbound method*:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def bar(self):
...         return 'Method bound to {!r}, from class Foo'.format(self)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<Instance of type {!r}>'.format(type(self))
...
>>> Foo.bar
<unbound method Foo.bar>
```

This object contains a reference to the original class still, as well as the original function object:

```
>>> Foo.bar.im_class
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Foo.bar.__func__  # new name, old name im_self still works too
<function bar at 0x105d2a9b0>
```

The term *unbound* here refers to the fact that it's not bound to an instance; however it *is* bound to the class.

The text tells you that it'll treat such unbound method objects the same as functions, when you stick them on another class. So if you do this, the method object will be *rebound* to the new class; the original function object is referenced and rebound to the new class:

```
>>> class Bar(Foo):
...     bar = Foo.bar   # an unbound method from the Foo class!
...
>>> Bar.bar
<unbound method Bar.bar>
>>> Bar.bar.im_class
<class '__main__.Bar'>
>>> Bar().bar()  # it'll work like any other method
"Method bound to <Instance of type <class '__main__.Bar'>>, from class Foo"
```

Here `Bar` is a subclass of `Foo`, and the unbound method object is re-bound to the class `Bar`.

However, the text states that this *won't* be done if you stick the unbound method onto a different class that is not a subclass of `Foo`:

```
>>> class Baz(object):   # not derived from Foo
...     bar = Foo.bar
...
>>> Baz.bar
<unbound method Foo.bar>
>>> Baz.bar.im_class
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> Baz().bar
<unbound method Foo.bar>
>>> Baz().bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method bar() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

You'd have to access the original function via `Foo.bar.__func__` or evade the descriptor protocol entirely by reaching in to the class `__dict__` (so use `Foo.__class__['bar']`) to avoid this issue altogether.

The text in the reference documentation is rather confusing, as this *doesn't* apply to fully bound methods even though it implies it should; these are never re-bound even when used on a class:

```
>>> class Spam(object):
...     bar = Foo().bar  # *bound* method, taken from an instance of Foo
...
>>> Spam.bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <Instance of type <class '__main__.Foo'>>>
>>> Spam().bar
<bound method Foo.bar of <Instance of type <class '__main__.Foo'>>>
>>> Spam().bar()
"Method bound to <Instance of type <class '__main__.Foo'>>, from class Foo"
```

Python 3 got rid of the unbound methods altogether; retrieving a function from a class object gives you the original function object. The above restriction has been dropped altogether.

Comment: @Pieters Thanks for your answer, so in your case the Baz().bar is unbound. But if I bounded to a instance of class Foo, say f = Foo(), then in Baz() I assign this bounded method to Baz().bar like bar = f.bar. If I call Baz().bar()  it will not be rebound to Baz, am I right ?

Comment: @Chrim: no. This doesn't extend to bound methods. Bound methods are *already* bound to an instance, and won't be re-bound.

Comment: @Chrim: that text is rather confusing and misleading, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Pieters fantastic answer, and with a little bit of reading the docs again and again, and experiments. I finally understand what the doc is trying to say:

A **user-defined method object** is an object with

1. a class(im_class)
2. a class instance (im_self)
3. a callable (im_func)

Every time we try to get an attributes of a class, a **user-define method  object** will be created if the attribute is the following:

1. user-defined function object
2. an unbound user-defined method object,
3. a class method object

1 is the normal case when the attributes is a function, 3 is when the function is a @classmethod

2 is the case mentioned by @Pieters, where the **attribute is already a user-defined method object from other class**, in this case, unless this object is from the same class (or derived class), no new user-defined method object will be created, and the old user-defined method will be used